# MySQL unique index on VARCHAR column (but only if longer than x characters)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a `customers` table that contains a unique identifier (medicare ID) that is truly unique for every individual who is issued one. Normally I would apply a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column to prevent duplication. However, there is a fringe case that comes up once in awhile in which partial values match across multiple individuals. Think of it as if SSNs were frequently obfuscated by only showing the middle two numbers (`***-11-****`). This is essentially the same situation. We want to store the partial value when we get it and then often update to the complete value as we get more data.

Ideally I want to store both partial and full values in the same column to make querying and searching simpler, but the unique index would trigger on these fringe cases. Is there some way to only apply unique constraint if the column meets a certain criteria? In this case it would be only if the column is exactly 11 characters long.

Comment: _"Is there some way to only apply unique constraint if the column meets a certain criteria?"_ - no, because then the values wouldn't be unique. As it is, some RDBMS _do_ support _filtered indexes_ but only for certain classes of values, such as non-`NULL` entries, but MySQL does not, so you'll need to put those in a separate table with an FK from your first.

Comment: As long as you can define how those shorter values look like, you can use unique index on a generated column to accomplish what you need.

Comment: You have too many requirements to roll into a single column.